# Google API sheets taking 10 seconds?

Tags: aws-lambda, google-sheets-api, alexa-skills-kit

Should a simple call to spreadsheets().values().update take close to 10 seconds to complete?

I'm developing an Alexa Skills python app that utilizes the Google Sheets API.The python code is served on AWS Lambda. Everything executes without error but the single call to .update().execute() is taking over 9 seconds to complete, regardless of the data set. This seems excessive - or is that what I should expect?

Here's the snippet. All I am doing is writing a single row with four words in four cells. SHEETS is the service object previously assigned from a discovery.build()

```
header = ['Date', 'Time', 'Stimulus', 'Response']
data = {"values": [header]}
start = time.time()
SHEETS.spreadsheets().values().update(spreadsheetId=sheetId, range='A1', body=data, valueInputOption='RAW').execute()
print 'Wrote data to Sheet1. It took %i seconds' % int(time.time() - start)
```

> Wrote data to Sheet1. It took 9 seconds

Comment: Apparently the time it takes is proportionate to the Lambda memory setting. Since it only takes a max of 108MB, I felt the default 128MB was sufficient.

Turns out that the CPU resources allocated are automatically proportional to the memory size. So the increase of the memory to 512MB  decreases the time it takes to 2 seconds, not becuase of the memory but the CPU resources assigned. UGH.

Now the question remains why does a simple REST call within the Google API python client require so much more CPU than all of my other Alexa Skills?

Answer (score 0):

Try turning up your RAM allocation and see what happens.  This also will provide more CPU.